# How to query the Entity Framework in a WCF Data Services OData Service from within the ServiceAuthorizationManager

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, rest, entity-framework-5, wcf-data-services

My FooData.svc.cs file looks like this: (**Take note of the undeclared object CurrentDataSource**.)

```
public class FooData : DataService<FooEntities>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
      // init code
    }

    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<someStoredProcedure_Result> someStoredProcedure(int param1, int param2)
    {
        return CurrentDataSource.someStoredProcedure(param1, param2).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

My Authorizer.cs file looks like this:

```
public class Authorizer : System.ServiceModel.ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        if (base.CheckAccessCore(operationContext))
        {
            if (IsAuthorized())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    private bool IsAuthorized(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
      // some code here that gets the authentication headers, 
      // etc from the operationContext

      // *********
      // now, how do I properly access the Entity Framework to connect 
      // to the db and check the credentials since I don't have access
      // to CurrentDataSource here
    }
}
```

Applicable section from Web.config, for good measure:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MyNamespace.Authorizer, MyAssemblyName" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

So my question has to do with where you see all the asterisks in the code in Authorizer.cs. What is the recommended way to connect to the Entity Framework from within the ServiceAuthorizationManager since I don't have access to CurrentDataSource there? Do I just establish a separate "connection"? e.g.

```
using (var db = new MyNamespace.MyEntityFrameworkDBContext())
{
    // linq query, stored proc, etc using the db object
}
```

To clarify, the above code works just fine. I'm just wondering if it's the correct way. By the way, this is a Visual Studio 2012 WCF Data Services project with .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered your own question. If you are concerned with the creation of DbContext for each IsAuthorized - then unless you are calling this functions hundreds of times during 1 request you should be fine. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647912/why-re-initiate-the-dbcontext-when-using-the-entity-framework),[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/07/tip-18-how-to-decide-on-a-lifetime-for-your-objectcontext.aspx) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813457/instantiating-a-context-in-linq-to-entities) recreation of EF context is not only inexpensive operation but also recommended.

EDIT:

Please note that DataService constructor is called after IsAuthorized, therefore independent instance of DbContext is the most likely the way to go.

Comment: I am concerned with creating a context when I don't need to. I thought that possibly there was a way of using the operationContext to cast it (or one of its properties) and somehow get at the CurrentDataSource of the FooData class. If that were the case there would be no need to create a DBContext object at all.

Comment: I checked the trace and DataService constructor is called after IsAuthorized. Therefore, creating context within IsAuthorized or Authorizer is in my opinion the way to go. I've edited the answer as well.